# NLog not writing to the EventLog

Tags: c#, event-log, nlog

I'm using NLog to record my logging, everything is working fine, but now I have installed the application on to a WebService in IIS 6, it is not logging to the EventLog, all other logs are working okay.

What do I need to configure to get this working on the Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161617/nlog-cant-write-to-event-log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have permissions to access the event log? You can try enabling logging for NLog itself to see where it's failing. Have a look at [Logging is not working - how to troubleshoot it?](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, did not know NLog could do that, it produces nothing in the log file either :-(