# How do I create a new log in the Event Viewer with Command Prompt? (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, event-log

I'm looking for a way to create a new log in the Windows Event Viewer. With eventcreate, I can create an event for a certain log and source, but if I give a non existing log name, I get an error saying the '....' log does not exist.

If I use the C# EventLog.CreateEventSource, the Log is automatically created.

So, how do I create such a log under Applications and Services Logs in Event Viewer?

And, if not possible with Command Prompt, is it possible in the Event Viewer itself to create an extra log? (I do not want to go and mess in the registry, because like that you can also create a log).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Windows EventLog source from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446691/how-to-create-windows-eventlog-source-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to writing a little command line utility myself.