# Windows 2008 - The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been dredging up an old classic ASP application and installing it on a windows 2008 server, but when it should throw an error, it seems to be throwing this error instead:

```
System

error '8013150a' 

The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security.
```

So it seems to be throwing a further error as I don't have permission to write to the event viewer, so I can't see what the original error is! 
I've looked into a lot of answers on this, such as adding registry permissions on the EventLog and Applications folders within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but without success.  I wonder if things are different for classic asp - has anyone come across this issue before that could help me sort this infuriating error out?

Thanks

EDIT - I have other .NET applications running on that server that write to the event viewer.  It does seem to be confined to the classic asp applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is probably trying to write to an event source that doesn't exist. You can create an event source as follows: [How to create Windows EventLog source from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446691/how-to-create-windows-eventlog-source-from-command-line).

Determine which event source your application is trying to write to and create it.

Comment: Thanks for this Michael - do you know how to find out what the event source would be? I thought it would be ASP, but that hasn't made any difference

Comment: I think this is going to require some digging and trial and error for you. Often the event log source is the name of the application logging the event. One way to get an exhaustive list of application log sources is to check the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControllSet/Services/EvetnLog/Application . There will be a large list of log sources. Check these sources on the legacy server on which your app was running. You'll need to use your domain knowledge to see if you can figure out which one is being used by your application.

Comment: Ok, I found it - the problem was it was a dll I was referring to that was throwing the error, and that was the one I needed to create a source for rather than my website application name etc. Thanks for that