# How to create an EventSource without admin rights?

Tags: .net, admin, etw-eventsource, eventsource

I have an scenario where I have to create event sources without admin rights as the app needs to do it at runtime.

The installer executes with admin rights so what I can do it to modify whatever it needs to be modified to avoid the need of admin rights.

Is there something I can change like permissions on registry entries, security policies or something that allows a normal user to create an EventSource?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource doesn't require admin rights. Explain what you do

Comment: Cool. We are installing an application once in a RemoteApp server (like a Citrix server) and executing the app for several different users. Every user requires a different source to log their data.

Comment: and what is now not working and why do you need admin rights?

Comment: To create an Eventsource you need admin rigths.

Comment: no, I use it daily ;)

Comment: Taken from the MSDN: "To create an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server 2003, you must have administrative privileges." https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need permissions not for EventSource, but for EventLog - there are different entities entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EventLog write permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245345/eventlog-write-permissions)

Comment: yeah, Sergey answered it. You talk about Eventlog, not ETW Eventsource events like you tagged your question. Change your question and explain now in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: Did you check my MSDN link? They talk all the time about eventsource

Comment: I did. This is for Eventlog. Here admin rights are needed. This is expected.