# Add IIS hosted WCF Service to Registry Editor to allow writing to Event Log

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, registry, event-log

I have a WCF Service that is not able to write to the Event Log because it does not have permission to create the event source. I have followed the instructions on the MSDN site found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516), however they are relatively non-descript.

What is the proper process for adding a WCF Service Reference to the Registry Editor under `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\MySourcesName]`

Do I need any `Name`, `Type`, `Data` values other than `(Default)`, `REG_SZ`, `(value not set)`

Comment: Is it a windows service or a IIS hosted one ?

Comment: You can try impersonation as in the link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx

Comment: This is for an IIS hosted service. sorry, i'll add that to my question.

Comment: Do you mean from code or from the command-line? See this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446691/how-to-create-windows-eventlog-source-from-command-line/1036133#1036133