# Custom httpModule is not logging to Windows Logs

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I have a problem with logging an message to EventViewer\WindowsLogs using a custom HTTPModule class. I've already try to run Visual Studio with admin rights, I also tried from IIS 6.0. It doesn't crash, it just doesn't add any code. Below it's the module class and the config file.

**HttpModule**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Chapter_V.HttpModules
{
    public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(OnAuthentication);
        }

        private void OnAuthentication(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            EventLog log = new EventLog();
            log.Source = "My First HttpModule";
            log.WriteEntry(name + " was authenticated !");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="MyHttpModule" type="Chapter_V.HttpModules.MyHttpModule,ChapterV"/>

      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>

      <add name="MyHttpModule" type="Chapter_V.HttpModules.MyHttpModule,ChapterV"/>
    </modules>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Do you have any ideea about this issue? (this is only for study purposes)

Answer (score 0):

Provided the user identity on your application pool has the rights to create event log entries. 
Try running the following script:

```
eventcreate /ID 1 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION  /SO "My First HttpModule" /D "My first log"
```

This will create a new event source named "My First HttpModule" under APPLICATION event log as INFORMATION event type.

Not sure of the exact reasons why, but a source must already exist (be created) in the event log before it can be used in code.

[Source of information is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446691/how-to-create-windows-eventlog-source-from-command-line)

Comment: Thank you, Brent. That line added an event log in the APPLICATION event log. I still don't get it why it doesn't want to add a log using my Http Module. I try it with the Visual Server web server (CTRL + F5)  and also from IIS. But no success.