# System.Security.SecurityException: An exception occurred during the Install phase while Installing service

Tags: c#, service, installation, visual-studio-2017, event-log

I am trying to install window service from command prompt. The installation of service is failed because the system throws an security issue. The error is

> Installing service SrvConfigurationManager...
>
> Creating EventLog source SrvConfigurationManager in log Application...
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
> System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

Installation is rolling back because the system is not been able to create event log. For the installation I have given the full control to `Network-Service` in Security and Application in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` in Registry Editor. Even though the same error persist.

I am trying to install window service like this from Command Prompt:

```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe "F:\Projects\ConfigManager\bin\Debug\SrvConfigurationManager.exe"
```

I have also tried to create the event log using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446691/how-to-create-windows-eventlog-source-from-command-line) reference but the result is same.Now my question is:

1. Anything wrong with my installation?
2. How do I install Windows Service?

Reference taken from

[How to: Install and Uninstall Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services)

[How to create a setup project for a Windows Service application in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/816169/how-to-create-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-service-application-in-vis)

[Eventcreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc755240(v=ws.11))

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: Yes I am running cmd as administrator.

Comment: Did you restart OS?

Comment: Why are you doing that using cmd? Can't you create a setup project for your service?

Comment: @ adamshakhabov I have restarted OS for several times. @Mohammad Hamoud I have created the setup but it says that `cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A windows Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Service Administrator tool or the NET START Command`

Comment: No, you are opening the service file check this out
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/816169/how-to-create-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-service-application-in-vis

Comment: I have tried to create setup also but the result is same

Answer (score 0):

Just run Developer Command Prompt for VS as Administration.  It will solve the problem of

> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
> System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security, State.