# How to clear a event log in Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, events, event-log, powershell-7.0

in Powershell 5 we can clear a Windows-Event-Log in this way:

> ```
> Get-EventLog -LogName * | % { Clear-EventLog -LogName $_.log }
> ```

how to do this in Powershell 7??? (using powershell only)

Powershell way of handling windows events is now with Get-WinEvent
but it appears no Clear-WinEvent is available

of course we can do this with wevtutil.exe
or even brute-forcing the logs file deletion after stopping the service...
but i'm asking only with native powershell code.

Comment: I don't see [Clear-EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) is deprecated aswell..

Comment: according to the MSDocs site, that cmdlet does NOT exist in ps7+. >>> Clear-EventLog (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7

Comment: yes... I noticed that... ;-) anyway it should now be "CLEAR-WINEVENT' for coherence with the evolution that is beeing done in powershell...

Comment: CLEAR-EVENTLOG was the companion of the deprecated GET-EVENTLOG.... so... thw new should be named CLEAR-WINEVENT for coherence with GET-WINEVENT... I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: `Get-Command *winevent*` on Posh 7.0.3 returns only `Get-WinEvent` and `New-WinEvent`. For PowerShell 5.1 it's the same. Seems like they are not supposed to be deleted or someone just forgot half of the features ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is interesting. `Clear-WinEvent` indeed is not part of PowerShell 7. There [was an issue raised](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12575) to get it added but doesn't like that's going anywhere without more action.

The Microsoft approved way to do this is:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management -UseWindowsPowerShell
Get-EventLog -LogName * | % { Clear-EventLog -LogName $_.log }
```

This [spins up a Windows PowerShell 5.1 process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7.1) that runs in the background and invokes the Cmdlet via implicit remoting... not the best.

A better way would be to leverage the .NET [**`EventLogSession.ClearLog`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogsession.clearlog?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Eventing_Reader_EventLogSession_ClearLog_System_String_) method:

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | foreach {
    [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession.ClearLog($_.LogName)
}
```

---

*Aside* - [PowerShell 7 module compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/module-compatibility?view=powershell-7.1) lists the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` module (that `Get-EventLog` and `Clear-EventLog` are part of) as 'Built into PowerShell 7'

Comment: yes... and I've been using .net Eventing to acomplish the objective... but it seams to me that a CLEAR-WINEVENT sould already be available... even if now a CLEAR-LINUXEVENT or even a CLEAR-OSXEVENT can appear in the scene with the Powershell avaailability to other OS(s)...

Comment: @ZEE - this question seems to be less "How to clear a event log in Powershell 7" and more "Why is there no Clear-Event command in Powershell 7"... as per linked issue the `Clear-EventLog` was based on a proprietary API.  
I agree it _should_ exist from a PS 5.1 feature-parity POV, but not from the POV of going from *Windows* PS 5.1 to open-source PS 7, based PS 6, in which `*-EventLog` cmdlets  where [removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/breaking-changes-ps6?view=powershell-7.1#-eventlog-cmdlets)

Comment: "The Microsoft approved way to do this is" can you source that?  I'd love to read more, thanks