# How to write to Windows Event Viewer Application Channel? (.NET)

Tags: .net, logging, event-handling

I am able to log to Windows Event Viewer using Serilog. However, it logs to Windows Logs / Application. I wish to log to Applications and Service Logs. I think I need to create a custom channel and then config the logger to send to that custom channel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756956(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
I think this custom channel is an application channel. When I research application channel the results always end up Application Insights. I am not using Azure. Just IIS.

Here is my C# code. Any Suggestions?

```
          Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug()
                      .WriteTo.EventLog("Laserfiche_Document_Finder", 
                       manageEventSource: true).CreateLogger();

            builder.Host.UseSerilog();
            

            "Serilog": {
        "using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" ],
        "Minimumlevel": {
          "Default": "Information"
        },
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "EventLog",
            "Args": {
              "source": "DLF",
              "manageEventSource": true
            }
          }
        ]
```

[image: Where I can it to be in Event Viewer]

Comment: I think this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446691/how-to-create-windows-eventlog-source-from-command-line has the answer i am looking for. I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace System.Diagnostics provides a class name as “EventLog” to create and write a message into the eventlog.

Let’s take an example, our goal is to write a simple C# .NET class which will create a new log name as “myEventLog” and write a message “I will not say I have failed 1000 times; I will say that I have discovered 1000 ways that can cause failure – Thomas Edison.” as an information.

To achieve this, we need to use the following methods, properties and enum which will be found in the System.Diagnostics namespace.

SourceExists: Determines whether an event source is registered on the local computer or not.

CreateEventSource: Establishes an application as able to write event information to a particular log on the system.
More details can be found at this link.

WriteEntry: Writes an entry in the event log, i.e., writes an information type entry, with the given message text, to the event log.
More details can be found at this link.

```
public class ClsEventLog
{
  public bool CreateLog(string strLogName)
  {
      bool Result = false;

      try
      {
              System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(strLogName, strLogName);
              System.Diagnostics.EventLog SQLEventLog =
          new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

              SQLEventLog.Source = strLogName;
              SQLEventLog.Log = strLogName;

              SQLEventLog.Source = strLogName;
              SQLEventLog.WriteEntry("The " + strLogName + " was successfully
      initialize component.", EventLogEntryType.Information);

              Result = true;
      }
      catch
      {
          Result = false;
      }

      return Result;
  }
  public void WriteToEventLog(string strLogName
                            , string strSource
                            , string strErrDetail)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.EventLog SQLEventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

      try
      {
          if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(strLogName))
                  this.CreateLog(strLogName);


          SQLEventLog.Source = strLogName;
          SQLEventLog.WriteEntry(Convert.ToString(strSource)
                                + Convert.ToString(strErrDetail),
          EventLogEntryType.Information);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          SQLEventLog.Source = strLogName;
          SQLEventLog.WriteEntry(Convert.ToString("INFORMATION: ")
                                + Convert.ToString(ex.Message),
          EventLogEntryType.Information);
      }
      finally
      {
          SQLEventLog.Dispose();
          SQLEventLog = null;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to set Log level explicite for EventLog.

EventLog provider does not inherit the default non-provider settings. If EventLog log settings aren't specified, they default to LogLevel.Warning.

```
"Logging": {
  "EventLog": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows-eventlog

Comment: That ends up writing an event to Windows Logs - Application. To create a custom event log I found. System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(strLogName, strLogName);